# SQL - Counting over several groups

Tags: sql, count, partition

I have a list of transactions where the ID's are repeated and I have the quantity of items being bought. I need to count the number of times that a particular number of items were purchased at once.

| Row | ItmNBR | TQTY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 5 |
| 2 | 123 | 5 |
| 3 | 123 | 5 |
| 3 | 456 | 25 |
| 4 | 456 | 19 |

I need to produce an out put like this...

| ItmNBR | QTY | Occurance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 5 | 3 |
| 123 | 19 | 1 |
| 123 | 25 | 1 |

I can get the first two columns of my result but when I attempt to counting over a partition I end up counting getting repeating numbers since I'm only looking up 9 items I just count the number of rows in which the Cnt is the same.

````
    TOT_IVO_ITM_QTY
     Count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY QTY) AS CNT
FROM dataset 
    WHERE YEAR(bus_dt) = 2021
    AND ITM_NBR IN (12639,12940,12949,12955,13485,13666,43950,631343,1103731)
    AND QTY BETWEEN 5 AND 25
    ORDER BY ITM_NBR
    ,QTY
    GROUP BY ITM_NBR, TOT_IVO_ITM_QTY```
````

Comment: Shouldn't `456` be in the result set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want `group by`:

```
select ItmNBR, QTY, count(*)
from t
group by ItmNBR, QTY
order by count(*) desc;
```

This assumes that you want the count by item and quantity, which seems to be the gist of the question.

Comment: Thank you so much... I was really overthinking that one